# Powershell file updating with future and past time

Tags: windows, powershell, scripting

I am having a text file that has content in this manner.

```
One;Thomas;Newyork;2020-12-31 14:00:00;0

Two;David;London;2021-01-31 12:00:00;0

Three;James;Chicago;2021-01-20 15:00:00;0

Four;Edward;India;2020-12-25 15:00:00;0
```

In these entries according to date time, two are past entries and two are future entries. The last 0 in the string indicates the Flag. With the past entries that flag needs to be changed to 1.

Consider all the entries are separated with the array. I tried this block of code but its not working to solve the problem here.

```
for ($item=0 ; $item -lt $entries.count ; $item++)
{
  if ($entries.DateTime[$item] -lt (Get-Date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd  HH:mm:ss"))
  {
    $cont = Get-Content $entries -ErrorAction Stop
    $string = $entries.number[$item] + ";" + $entries.name[$item] + ";" + 
    $entries.city[$item]+ ";" + $entries.DateTime[$item] 
    $lineNum = $cont | Select-String $string
    $line = $lineNum.LineNumber + 1
    $cont[$line] = $string + ";1"
    Set-Content -path $entries
  }
}
```

I am getting errors with this concept.

Output should come as:-

One;Thomas;Newyork;2020-12-31 14:00:00;1 ((Past Deployment with respect to current date)

Two;David;London;2021-01-31 12:00:00;0

Three;James;Chicago;2021-01-20 15:00:00;0

Four;Edward;India;2020-12-25 15:00:00;1 (Past Deployment with respect to current date)

This output needs to be overwritten on the file from where the content is extracted ie Entries.txt

Comment: According to the fact that your datas are in a file called datas.txt, you should import the file with Import-csv, change the last column and export it again. Import-Csv allow you to add header.

Comment: Also [edit] the question and show what errors you are getting. Is there an error message? Do you get wrong output? Something else?

Answer (score 0):

```
param(
    $exampleFileName = "d:\tmp\file.txt"
)

@"
One;Thomas;Newyork;2020-12-31 14:00:00;0

Two;David;London;2021-01-31 12:00:00;0

Three;James;Chicago;2021-01-20 15:00:00;0

Four;Edward;India;2020-12-25 15:00:00;0
"@ | Out-File $exampleFileName


Remove-Variable out -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

Get-Content $exampleFileName | ForEach-Object {
    $out += ($_ -and [datetime]::Parse(($_ -split ";")[3]) -gt [datetime]::Now) ? $_.SubString(0,$_.Length-1) + "1`r`n" : $_ + "`r`n"
}

Out-File -InputObject $out  -FilePath $exampleFileName
```

Comment: Is it possible to overwrite the same file instead of deleting the old file and renaming the temp file??

Comment: if you so wish.